# Limiting the number of concurrent futures in join_all!()

Tags: rust, concurrency, rust-tokio, rust-futures

How to make Rust execute all given futures (like `join_all!`) limiting to execute say 10 futures at once?

I need to download files from a big number of servers, but query no more than 10 servers simultaneously (to accurately measure their timeouts: if I query too many servers at once,, they timeout, even if the servers by themselves are fast).

Comment: I would say use a thread pool. But if you want to stick with async how about using a semaphore flagged up 10 times initially. [Here's a crate](https://docs.rs/async-semaphore/latest/async_semaphore/). [And another](https://github.com/nathdobson/async-weighted-semaphore) You'll need some special async semaphore of course not a normal thread based done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with the `futures` crate by creating a stream of futures (for example by using [`futures::stream::iter`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3/futures/stream/fn.iter.html)) and call [`buffered`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.buffered) or [`buffer_unordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.buffer_unordered) to execute at most *n* futures in parallel.

```rust
use futures::prelude::*;

// create an iterator of futures to execute
let futures =
    (0..50).map(|n| async move {
        fetch(format!("https://server-{}.example.com", n)).await
    });

// create a buffered stream that will execute up to 10 futures in parallel
// (without preserving the order of the results)
let stream = futures::stream::iter(futures).buffer_unordered(10);

// wait for all futures to complete
let results = stream.collect::<Vec<_>>().await;
```

[Run example in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8d7f7b1c1f0a38aa25d43c281b379c7f)

Comment: Could you share how this could be done non-async with Rayon parallel library?